# Meteor allow deny not working in collection fs context

Tags: security, meteor, collectionfs

Meteor version 1.0.4
I removed autopublish and insecure
Allow and deny work fine for Collections but not for FS.Collection

I have this FS collection:

Avatars = new FS.Collection("avatars", {stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("avatars", {path: 'PATH_TO_FILES'})]});

On server side:

```
Avatars.allow({
 download:function(userId,doc){
  ...
 },
 insert: function(userId,doc){
  console.log("just to check");
  return userId
 },
  update....
});
```

But with Avatars.insert in client side, allow is not called

I found no error but the following warning:
Meteor._wrapAsync has been renamed to Meteor.wrapAsync

Thank you for your help

Christophe

Comment: Are you saying that the "just to check" is not appearing in the server's log?  Looking at your `allow.insert` function, I don't see why it should return an error -- `userId` (if defined) is truthy and so should allow the insert.  Have you tried returning `false` to see if that triggers an error?

Comment: Yes for both:
=> If I return false, I haven't access denied on client side (Ihave the issue only for FS collection not for usual Colletion)
=>just to check doesn't appear in server's log
 / amazing isn't it? I'm sure I made a silly but simple mistake somewhere

Comment: I was unable to reproduce.  This may seem really trivial but are you sure you defined everything in the appropriate spot (`allow` on the server, `Avatars` on both client and server)?  You're not overwriting the `allow` function anywhere, are you -- like it's not maybe defined twice on your server and you don't realize it?  Maybe seeing your actual client code would help (but probably not)?

Comment: Thank you Carson, an old file with allow method still existed!